# vs xamarin.ios broker connection issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

It connects sometimes, sometime it fails, partially successful or fully successful. See log file bellow.

I have tried these hints: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/

```
Starting Broker 4.1.1.3 in port 52919...
Couldn't connect to 192.168.67.128. Please try again.
Disconnected from Mac 192.168.67.128 (192.168.67.128)
The operation has timed out.
Downloading /Users/ibolaji/Library/Logs/Xamarin-4.1/2016-06-29__18-42-39.6984.Broker.stderr.log...
Starting Broker 4.1.1.3 in port 51080...
Disconnected from Mac 192.168.67.128 (192.168.67.128)
Couldn't connect to 192.168.67.128. Please try again.
There was an error while trying to connect the client vs6984bolaj to the server.
Installing Broker 4.1.1.3...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (512/4998 KB) 10%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (1008/4998 KB) 20%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (1504/4998 KB) 30%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (2000/4998 KB) 40%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (2512/4998 KB) 50%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (3008/4998 KB) 60%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (3504/4998 KB) 70%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (4000/4998 KB) 80%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (4512/4998 KB) 90%...
Uploaded Broker 4.1.1.3 100%
Starting Broker 4.1.1.3 in port 50337...
Couldn't connect to 192.168.67.128. Please try again.
Disconnected from Mac 192.168.67.128 (192.168.67.128)
The operation has timed out.
Downloading /Users/ibolaji/Library/Logs/Xamarin-4.1/2016-06-29__18-42-39.6984.Broker.log...
Downloading /Users/ibolaji/Library/Logs/Xamarin-4.1/2016-06-29__18-42-39.6984.Broker.stderr.log...
Installing Broker 4.1.1.3...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (512/4998 KB) 10%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (1008/4998 KB) 20%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (1504/4998 KB) 30%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (2000/4998 KB) 40%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (2512/4998 KB) 50%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (3008/4998 KB) 60%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (3504/4998 KB) 70%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (4000/4998 KB) 80%...
Uploading Broker 4.1.1.3 (4512/4998 KB) 90%...
Uploaded Broker 4.1.1.3 100%
Starting Broker 4.1.1.3 in port 56200...
Couldn't connect to 192.168.67.128. Please try again.
Disconnected from Mac 192.168.67.128 (192.168.67.128)
The operation has timed out.
Downloading /Users/ibolaji/Library/Logs/Xamarin-4.1/2016-06-29__18-42-39.6984.Broker.log...
Downloading /Users/ibolaji/Library/Logs/Xamarin-4.1/2016-06-29__18-42-39.6984.Broker.stderr.log...
Starting Broker 4.1.1.3 in port 53605...
Disconnected from Mac 192.168.67.128 (192.168.67.128)
Couldn't connect to 192.168.67.128. Please try again.
There was an error while trying to connect the client vs6984bolaj to the server.
Starting Broker 4.1.1.3 in port 56304...
Couldn't connect to 192.168.67.128. Please try again.
Disconnected from Mac 192.168.67.128 (192.168.67.128)
There was an error while trying to connect the client vs6984bolaj to the server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use another  VPN client application? Disconnect in VPN application and try to connect in Xamarin Mac Agent. And mayby this help to you. 
[Connection Troubleshooting](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/)
I hope its help for you.